# Customise the Tumblr 'Submit' Form

Tags: tumblr

I'd like to restyle the default submission block on a tumblr theme that is here on tumblr themes: name.tumblr.com/submit

But I'm struggling to find if this is possible.

Comment: AFAIK there is no official method to do this: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2, you would need to either sniff or mask the default submit form.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS filters or positioned overlays; it being an iframe restricts most of the usual options.

The only other method I've got to work is applying a background image and messing with the iframe's opacity.